# Get a user's current location

Tags: php, geolocation, ip

How can I determine a user's current location based on IP address (I guess it works this way).

Comment: [MaxMind GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location) is a good service. They also have a free city-level lookup service.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [GeoIP Country Whois Locator](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3582-PHP-Determine-the-country-of-an-IP-address-using-GeoIP.html) found at [PHPClasses](http://www.phpclasses.org).

Answer (score 40):

```
<?php
$user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));
$country = $geo["geoplugin_countryName"];
$city = $geo["geoplugin_city"];
?>
```

Comment: Geoplugin is not best platform. It is limited to 120 actions per minute. It worked for me, but lately it started to show 403 for all requests from my server. Who knows why. (I haven't made those 120 connections in one minute)

Comment: Useless with those limits.

Answer (score 35):

**Edited**

Change [freegeoip.net](https://freegeoip.net) into [ipinfo.io](http://ipinfo.io/)

```
<?php    

function get_client_ip()
{
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    } else if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    } else {
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    }

    return $ipaddress;
}
$PublicIP = get_client_ip();
$json     = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/$PublicIP/geo");
$json     = json_decode($json, true);
$country  = $json['country'];
$region   = $json['region'];
$city     = $json['city'];
?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Is there a workaround for localhost servers? My ip address keeps coming up as ::1

Comment: @vince Localhost always return ::1 ip address

Comment: __deprecation_message__: "This API endpoint is deprecated and will stop working on July 1st, 2018. For more information please visit: https://github.com/apilayer/freegeoip#readme",

Comment: For what is it necessary to check all the forwarded ip? I thought only check `if(isset(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR))` is necessary.

Comment: And in many countries this will get you the location of the ISP not the actual user

Comment: Found a free API https://ipapi.co/$PublicIP/json , or also single fields can be queried much quicker https://ipapi.co/$PublicIP/languages !  Check the docs at https://ipapi.co/api/#location-of-a-specific-ip

Answer (score 19):

```
<?php
    $query = @unserialize (file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'));
    if ($query && $query['status'] == 'success') {
        echo 'Hey user from ' . $query['country'] . ', ' . $query['city'] . '!';
    }
    foreach ($query as $data) {
        echo $data . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Try this code using this source. *It works!

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Is it a free API?

Answer (score 10):

Try this code using the [hostip.info](http://www.hostip.info/) service:

```
$country=file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=');
echo $country;

// Reformat the data returned (Keep only country and country abbr.)
$only_country=explode (" ", $country);

echo "Country : ".$only_country[1]." ".substr($only_country[2],0,4);
```

Comment: instead of exploding the return you can use the json as return. http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php

Comment: $json_string = 'http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata, true);

Comment: This site is not available anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As PHP relies on a server, the real-time location can’t be provided. Only a static location can be provided. It is better to avoid to rely on the JavaScript for a location rather than using PHP.

But there is a need to post the JavaScript data to PHP, so that it can easily be accessible to a program on the server.

Answer (score 1):

An IP address gives you a quite unreliable location. You could Ajax the location upon load with JavaScript if it isn't critical to have the location at first. (Also, the user needs to give you its permission to access it.)

[HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

The old [freegeoip API is now deprecated](https://github.com/apilayer/freegeoip) and will be discontinued on 2018-07-01.

The new API is from *[ipstack](https://ipstack.com)*. You have to create the account in ipstack. Then you can use the access key in the API URL.

```
$url = "http://api.ipstack.com/122.167.180.20?access_key=ACCESS_KEY&format=1";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($response);
$city  = $response->city; // You can get all the details like longitude, latitude from the '$response'.
```

For more information, check at *[freegeoip](https://github.com/apilayer/freegeoip)* (GitHub).

Comment: This is a paid service.

Comment: The question is not about free service

Comment: they have a free. limited tier