# PHP - using date to find out daylight savings time

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I want to give date() a date and have it return if that date is DST or not. Running PHP 5.4.7 via xampp on a windows 7 box. A linux box running PHP 5.2.8 returns 0 no matter what date I give it.

What's wrong with my code?

```
echo date('I', strtotime('30-Mar-2013'));
# should return a 1 but returns 0

echo date('I', strtotime('30-Mar-2013 America/Los_Angeles'))."<br>"; # returns 0
echo date('I', strtotime('31-Mar-2013 America/Los_Angeles'))."<br>"; # returns 1
```

The switch between DST should be between 9-Mar-2013 - 10-Mar-2013.

At this point, the question is, why doesn't my PHP code return 1.

Comment: It returns a `1` here. Are you using PHP5?

Comment: PHP 5.4.7 (xampp). For some reason it returns 0 for me, even with America/Los_Angeles set. I tried this on a linux and windows machine.

Comment: @Jevgeni Bogatyrjov: `strtotime()` doesn't change server's timezone settings and resulted timestamp doesn't store any TZ information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181667/how-to-check-if-a-time-offset-is-in-daylight-savings-time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use `strtotime` because it creates a UTC timestamp, which removes the timezone information.  Instead, just use `DateTime`

```
$date = new DateTime('30-Mar-2013 America/Los_Angeles');
echo $date->format('I');
# 1

$date = new DateTime('31-Mar-2013 America/Los_Angeles');
echo $date->format('I');
# 1

$date = new DateTime('09-Mar-2013 America/Los_Angeles');
echo $date->format('I');
# 0

$date = new DateTime('10-Mar-2013 America/Los_Angeles');
echo $date->format('I');
# 0
```

Notice that the DST is still 0 on that last one?  That's because the transition happens at 2:00 AM:

```
$date = new DateTime('10-Mar-2013 01:00 America/Los_Angeles');
echo $date->format('I');
# 0

$date = new DateTime('10-Mar-2013 02:00 America/Los_Angeles');
echo $date->format('I');
# 1
```

This is a "spring-forward" transition, where the clock jumps from 2:00 to 3:00.

Beware of ambiguity during fall-back transitions, where the clock jumps from 2:00 back to 1:00

```
$date = new DateTime('3-Nov-2013 01:00 America/Los_Angeles');
echo $date->format('I');
# 1
```

There are two 1:00 AMs, and this is taking the first one.  It is ambiguous, because we might have meant the second one, and that is not represented.

One would think that PHP would allow either of the following:

```
new DateTime('3-Nov-2013 01:00 -0700 America/Los_Angeles')  #PDT
new DateTime('3-Nov-2013 01:00 -0800 America/Los_Angeles')  #PST
```

But these don't seem to work when I tested.  I also tried ISO format dates.  Anyone know how to properly distinguish ambiguous values in PHP?  If so, please edit or update in comments.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of ambiguity during fall-back transitions, where the clock jumps from 2:00 back to 1:00
`$date = new DateTime('3-Nov-2013 02:01 America/Los_Angeles');`

`echo $date->format('I');`

## 0

There are two 1:00 AMs, and 2:01 is taking the second one o'clock plus 1 hour and 1 minute.