# wordpress plugin which user can search store based on their location

Tags: php, wordpress

If want to develop a wordpress website like zomoto I want to know how to set user location detector on the website page so that user can get stores based on their selected place
and after the store and food is selected it should show the delivery time of like with 45 min or 60 min from the restaurant to their place selected

Comment: You could directly use wordpress theme that handle that like https://themeforest.net/item/matur-food-delivery-ordering-wordpress-theme/21120158?s_rank=1. But it depends on all of your needs.

Comment: Or this theme wich seems good : http://foodbakery.chimpgroup.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getCurrentPosition()` method to get the user's position. For example:

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(userPosition);
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
function userPosition(position) {
    console.log(position) 
}
```

Or using if you want to use `php` please refer to [Get user's current location in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398674/get-users-current-location-in-php)