# How to find user location full address

Tags: php, compass-geolocation

I am trying to find user location full address using Geoplugin APIs but it only gives me country of location instead of full address when I execute address. I want to get the exact location of the user as I am using it for plotting start point in a google map. My code is below

```
function ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location", $deep_detect = TRUE) {
    $output = NULL;
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if ($deep_detect) {
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
    }
    $purpose    = str_replace(array("name", "\n", "\t", " ", "-", "_"), NULL, strtolower(trim($purpose)));
    $support    = array("country", "countrycode", "state", "region", "city", "location", "address");
    $continents = array(
        "AF" => "Africa",
        "AN" => "Antarctica",
        "AS" => "Asia",
        "EU" => "Europe",
        "OC" => "Australia (Oceania)",
        "NA" => "North America",
        "SA" => "South America"
    );
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && in_array($purpose, $support)) {
        $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));
        if (@strlen(trim($ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode)) == 2) {
            switch ($purpose) {
                case "location":
                    $output = array(
                        "city"           => @$ipdat->geoplugin_city,
                        "state"          => @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName,
                        "country"        => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName,
                        "country_code"   => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode,
                        "continent"      => @$continents[strtoupper($ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode)],
                        "continent_code" => @$ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode
                    );
                    break;
                case "address":
                    $address = array($ipdat->geoplugin_countryName);
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_regionName) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_city) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    $output = implode(", ", array_reverse($address));
                    break;
                case "city":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    break;
                case "state":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "region":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "country":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName;
                    break;
                case "countrycode":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

echo = ip_info("Visitor", "address");
```

Comment: An IP address will practically never return the exact address of the person that uses it. A city is as close as you will get (and even then it's often not accurate).

Comment: which Technology should I use?

Comment: The only way to get someones exact address is to ask them. Otherwise it's (luckily) impossible to find out where someone lives just by having them visit your website.

Comment: try this, i think its best solution for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398674/get-users-current-location/42679526#42679526

Comment: [Mikael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15338791) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68703205) saying "what is missing for address search code too big I had to put it in pastebin pastebin.com/8DFGEnPx"

Answer (score 0):

You can not find user exact address by using IP. But I can tell how you can find it without asking them. Its not the illegal because your code will ask a permission from them. 
You cant do it by just using PHP you will need a javascript code too..

Lets check detecting address by using Google Maps API and Javascript. For more information search for it. Or just use  [Google MAPS API for JavaScript Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

geocoordinates.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['lat'], $_POST['lng'])) {
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $lng = $_POST['lng'];

    $url = sprintf("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%s,%s", $lat, $lng);

    $content = file_get_contents($url); // get json content

    $metadata = json_decode($content, true); //json decoder

    if(count($metadata['results']) > 0) {
        // for format example look at url
        // https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452
        $result = $metadata['results'][0];

        // save it in db for further use
        echo $result['formatted_address'];

    }
    else {
        // no results returned
    }
}

?>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geocoding Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(savePosition, positionError, {timeout:10000});
      } else {
          //Geolocation is not supported by this browser
      }
  }

  // handle the error here
  function positionError(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var message = error.message;

      alert(message);
  }

  function savePosition(position) {
            $.post("geocoordinates.php", {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude});
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="getLocation();">Get My Location</button>
</body>
</html>
```